# onChildAdded not working correctly in my case

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When activity started it shows all the data in list view by getting data from firebase. This is working fine according to my desire but when i add new node to the firebase database it will not go into the 
if condition that is `if (snapchat.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Order"))` and all the below code and also not set the adapter 
here is my code below
please help.
**and sorry for my english**

```
for (DataSnapshot snapchat: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    if (snapchat.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Order")) {} else {
        for (DataSnapshot lat: snapchat.getChildren()) {
            if (isLatitudeGet) {
                try {
                    Longitude = Double.parseDouble(lat.getValue().toString());
                    addresses = location.getFromLocation(latitude, Longitude, 1);
                    if (addresses.size() > 0)
                        address = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Card card = new Card(dataSnapshot.getKey(), lat.getValue().toString(), tempLatitude, address);
            cardArrayAdapter.add(card);
            listView.setAdapter(cardArrayAdapter);
            isLatitudeGet = false;
        } else {
            isLatitudeGet = true;
            tempLatitude = lat.getValue().toString();
            try {
                String p = lat.getValue().toString();
                latitude = Double.parseDouble(p);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            }
        }
```

Comment: When you are a new node in the database can it be upper case?

Comment: Its Google built-in push Id and its first character is upperCase @AlexMamo

Comment: which listener you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

It will not go into the if condition because your if condition is empty.

```
if (snapchat.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Order")) {}
```

See the curly braces, are empty. Everything it's in your else statemnet. To solve this, either move all that code into the if statement or either use:

```
if (!snapchat.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Order")) {}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No this is working fine for me for the first time when activity start but when i add new node with the same type (Previous nodes) its not going into if and also in else

Comment: If it's true, it will go to the if statement which is empty and nothing will happen. Make it false, what's happening? Is the else statement called? If it is not, then the condition is always true.

Comment: Did my answer helped you?